# Populate Dynamically created ASPX Page

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, webforms

Well The title might be a lil confusing, what I am currently doing is creating an aspx form dynamically and saving its data by using Server.Transfer("PrssPage.aspx").

On ProcessPage.aspx I am using the Previous Page property to save the data entered by the user using the dynamically created form.

Each Dynamic Form is provided an ID for example 123.aspx

Now what I want to achieve is to repopulate the dynamically created aspx page with the user input values from database, plz note here that I do not have an aspx.cs page getting dynamically generated. I am only generating aspx page.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the form dynamically, why not retrieve the data from the database and populate the form fields with this data, dynamically of course?

Take a look in [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx) if it helps.

Comment: Hi Leniel, I am able to get the data back from the database, since there is no associated .cs file with the form that's getting dynamically generated I am unable to populate its fields, What I need is to dynamically load this file just as we load ascx file.

Comment: @Sandhurst: i got the point. I've never seen something to load an .aspx page. I've just used the dynamic loading with ascx custom controls.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to crack open your nearest ASP.NET book.  Your question is too vague to give you any helpful answers.  Here are some things to ponder:

Are you really creating a NEW .aspx Page?  WHY?  I find it hard to picture a scenario where this is helpful or desirable.  Are you sure you don't mean that you're just dynamically creating controls on a given page? (and if not... why not?)

Why are you processing the input on a different page?  Unnecessary.  If you use a single page, then the ViewState will repopulate the page's controls for you.

Your comment to the first answer makes little sense.  Your code is running *somewhere*, and that is where you can reload the DB data and populate the fields.